# How can float virtual keyboard over html element in mobile chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, virtual-keyboard, mobile-chrome

VirtualKeyboard API is deprecated in mobile chrome.

but i need floating virtual keyboard over html element.

how can i implement this javascript or html or css in chrome?

```js
navigator.virtualKeyboard.overlaysContent = true // i want below code but deprecated.
```

Comment: Would you mind being more precise in your question? What exactly do you want to achieve, and in which situation? For example, why is the native on-screen keyboard not enough for your situation?

Comment: @Andy For my app, I want to make toggleable custom virtual keyboard(for emoticon) and default virtual keyboard if click button. But when i implent it, notice it, Unless floating default virtual keyboard, toggle process is not smothly(1. default virtual keyboard -> 2. click toggle button -> 3. default virtual keyboard hidden -> 4. custom virtual keyboard displayed(but here awkward because this process scroll move)) but i think if both virtual keyboard displayed same time and same height(overlay) when focus input element and when toggle just removed only default virtual keyboard it be natural

Comment: If you have a working code, please try to create a [Minimum Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question. Place the two buttons etc.